# mysql most efficient way to store user agent, referral etc

Tags: php, mysql, store, user-agent

What is the best way to store user agent, referral etc on each page request so i can track these actions for future statistics etc?

Would it be best to store for every page request user agent,referral on a new row in 1 or 2 tables?

would it be better to check if the user agent,referral has changed and if so then insert a new row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend PHP Session, You can easily store their information page to page until they leave your website.

One Page:

```
$_SESSION['userAgent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Second Page:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']!=$_SESSION['userAgent']){
echo 'User Agent Has Changed!';
}else{
echo 'User Agent Is The Same!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your HTTP server is already capable of logging each request, including the user agent, referral and time. It would be more efficient to get a proper log parser than constantly query the database.